# Extract email addresses from a website using scripts

Tags: bash, email, web

Given a website, I wonder what is the best procedure, programmatically and/or using scripts, to extract all email addresses that are present on each page in plain text in the form XXXX@YYYYY.ZZZZ from that link and all sites underneath, recursively or until some fixed depth.

Comment: hope this helps; http://superuser.com/questions/518736/send-emails-in-a-non-interactive-way-in-os-x

Comment: If this is your (or your client's) web site, you should have much easier ways to get the addresses than scraping the web pages. Even if the data has been lost, you can grep the local copies of the pages as shown by other posters.
**But if it is not your site, extracting the emails seems very unethical, and certainly extremely bad for your karma**. You have been warned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using shell programming you can achieve your goal using 2 programs piped together:

- [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html): will get all pages
- [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html): will filter and give you only the emails

An example:

```
wget -q -r -l 5 -O - http://somesite.com/ | grep -E -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b"
```

**wget**, in quiet mode (**-q**), is  getting all pages recursively (**-r**) with maximum depth level of 5 (**-l 5**) from somesite.com.br and printing everything to stdout (**-O -**).

**grep** is using an extended regular expression (**-E**) and showing only (**-o**) email address.

All emails are going to be printed to standard output and you can write them to a file by appending `> somefile.txt` to the command.

Read the `man` pages for more documentation on [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) and [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

This example was tested with GNU [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) version 4.2.37(1)-release, GNU grep 2.12 and GNU Wget 1.13.4.

Comment: Great answer +1, but just to be clear the regexp provided here is not going to catch all emails.

Comment: @dacwe Could you expand on which emails the regex misses?

Answer (score 10):

First use [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) to recursively download pages from the URL. The `-l` option is the recusion depth, set to `1` below:

```
$ mkdir site
$ cd site
$ wget -q -r -l1  http://www.foobar.com
```

Then run a recursive [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) to extract the email addresses. (The regex below is not perfect and may need to be tweaked if you find that not all addresses are being picked up.)

```
$ grep -hrio "\b[a-z0-9.-]\+@[a-z0-9.-]\+\.[a-z]\{2,4\}\+\b" *
```

As an aside, `wget` does have an option (`-O -`) to print downloaded content to stdout instead of saving it to disk but, unfortunately, it does not work in recursive (`-r`) mode.

Comment: I tried it with a small file I built and which contains 3 email addresses, but it does not work

Comment: where can I get information about what each thing means in your search pattern?

Comment: Please add the contents of your file to the question so that we can see why it is not working.

Comment: yes, the file contains just one line; "john@gmail.com , blue@hotmail.com"

Comment: @flow: To see the information about each thing, read about Regex searching (see [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/)). Another place is to look at the man pages: `man grep`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have used [wget](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~bioskill/MAN/wget.html) to get at the pages recursively, and then locate the addresses using regular expressions (I would have used a [python script](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for that, but almost any environment can provide the same functionality).

Answer (score 0):

Point 1). Developers add eMail ID in HTML entity format (rish) [HTML Entity](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp) :

Point 2). Emails are written on href="mailto:your@example.com".
So we can take this for Regular expresion.

```
<?php
    $str = '<div class="call-to-action ">
    <a title="Email" class="contact contact-main contact-email " 
    href="mailto:info@canberraeyelaser.com.au?subject=Enquiry%2C%20sent%20from%20yellowpages.com.au&amp;
    body=%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A------------------------------------------%0AEnquiry%20via%20yellowpages.com.au%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fyellowpages.com.au%2Fact%2Fphillip%2Fcanberra-eye-laser-15333167-listing.html%3Fcontext%3DbusinessTypeSearch" 
    rel="nofollow" data-email="info@canberraeyelaser.com.au">
    <span class="glyph icon-email border border-dark-blue with-text"></span><span class="contact-text">Email</span>
    <a href="mailto:&#114;&#105;&#115;&#104;&#97;&#98;&#104;&#100;&#117;&#98;&#101;&#121;&#50;&#48;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;">
    </a>
    </div>';

// $str = file_get_contents(http://example.com) ; (to get emails from URL in place of file_get_contents i use to prefer CURL) .

     $str = html_entity_decode($str);

    $regex = "/mailto:([^?]*)/";
    if ($rex = preg_match_all($regex, $str,$matches_out)) {

        echo "Found a match!";
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($matches_out[0]);
    } else {
        echo "The regex pattern does not match. :(";
    }

    ?>
```