# how to extract email from website site recursively through linux command

Tags: linux, email, recursion, grep, wget

I want to extract email form site recursively such that if a site has other links for email, it would traverse those pages as well and extract the email-id:s.

I did the following for depth level of 2:

```
wget -r -l 2 -O - some site name |grep -E -o "[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}">>some.txt
```

But when i execute this command it would just create a file "`some.txt`" and would not extract any email-id:s.

Comment: goto this link... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858344/extract-email-addresses-from-a-website-using-scripts

Comment: @user3125133 i have gone through the link and it says we cannot use -O with -r ,it won't output the recursive link's to standard uotput ,so is there no way to output recursive linek to standard output

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a recursive wget and store the site locally, and then do a recursive grep (grep -r) across the site on your local file system? Just add an rm -Rf to the end of the script to delete the site when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

As per using PHP:
Point 1). Developers add eMail ID in HTML entity format (rish) HTML Entity :

Point 2). Emails are written on href="mailto:your@example.com". So we can take this for Regular expresion.

```
<?php
    $str = '<div class="call-to-action ">
    <a title="Email" class="contact contact-main contact-email " 
    href="mailto:info@canberraeyelaser.com.au?subject=Enquiry%2C%20sent%20from%20yellowpages.com.au&amp;
    body=%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A------------------------------------------%0AEnquiry%20via%20yellowpages.com.au%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fyellowpages.com.au%2Fact%2Fphillip%2Fcanberra-eye-laser-15333167-listing.html%3Fcontext%3DbusinessTypeSearch" 
    rel="nofollow" data-email="info@canberraeyelaser.com.au">
    <span class="glyph icon-email border border-dark-blue with-text"></span><span class="contact-text">Email</span>
    <a href="mailto:&#114;&#105;&#115;&#104;&#97;&#98;&#104;&#100;&#117;&#98;&#101;&#121;&#50;&#48;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;">
    </a>
    </div>';

// $str = file_get_contents(http://example.com) ; (to get emails from URL in place of file_get_contents i use to prefer CURL) .

     $str = html_entity_decode($str);

    $regex = "/mailto:([^?]*)/";
    if ($rex = preg_match_all($regex, $str,$matches_out)) {

        echo "Found a match!";
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($matches_out[0]);
    } else {
        echo "The regex pattern does not match. :(";
    }

    ?>
```